# Error al llamar el activity en OnCreate con webservices

Tags: java, mysql, android

voy a dar un poco mas de contexto estoy tratando llamar una lista de una tabla alojada en una base de datos de mysql por medio de webservices, y quiero mostrarla en la fragment list, como un array recuperado en la funcion que se llama buscarProducto

public class MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

```
private final List<Mesas> mValues;
private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Mesas> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
    mValues = items;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_mesas, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.txtViewNumeroMesa.setText(holder.mItem.getNum_mesa_app());
    holder.txtViewMesero.setText(holder.mItem.getNombremes_app());

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
                
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final TextView txtViewMesero;
    public final TextView txtViewNumeroMesa;

    public Mesas mItem;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        txtViewMesero =  view.findViewById(R.id.txtMesero);
        txtViewNumeroMesa = view.findViewById(R.id.txtNumeroMesa);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + " '" + txtViewNumeroMesa.getText() +"'";
    }
}
```

}

```
private void buscarProducto(String URL) {
       JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
               JSONObject jsonObject = null;
               mesasList = new ArrayList<>();
               for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                   try {
                       jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                       mesasList.add(new Mesas(jsonObject.getString("num_mesa"), jsonObject.getString("mesero")));

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR DE CONEXION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR DE CONEXION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
       );
       requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
       requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

   }


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mesas_list, container, false);

       // Set the adapter
       if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
           Context context = view.getContext();
           recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
           if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
               recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
           } else {
               recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
           }
           //Lista de Mesas

           buscarProducto("http://localhost/TLKRestaurant/buscarmesas.php");

           //Asociacion de el adaptador a el RecyclerView
           adapterMesas = new MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter(mesasList, mListener);
           recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterMesas);
       }
       return view;
   }
```

El logcat manda el siguiente error

2020-06-28 21:16:02.176 13942-13942/com.androidavanzado.tlkcomandas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.androidavanzado.tlkcomandas, PID: 13942
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at com.androidavanzado.tlkcomandas.MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount(MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter.java:53)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4044)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3534)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25448)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25448)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25448)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6884)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25448)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25448)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6884)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25448)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6884)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:739)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25448)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3361)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2203)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1934)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8127)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)

Comment: Hola Camara. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir que intentas hacer? Así podemos guiarte un poco.

Comment: Cual es el error mostrado en el LogCat ? es importante agregar esta informaciòn, revisa [ask], edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: El problema se presenta en el Adapter MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter.java agregalo

Comment: ya lo agregue a la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el valor del ArrayList de la variable mesasList tiene valor null,

```
 //Asociacion de el adaptador a el RecyclerView
  adapterMesas = new MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter(mesasList, mListener);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterMesas);
```

debes asegurar que la peticiòn en verdad obtenga resultados,  y muy importante realizar este llamado dentro del callback `onResponse()` de la peticiòn Volley:

```
@Override
           public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
               JSONObject jsonObject = null;
               mesasList = new ArrayList<>();
               for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                   try {
                       jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                       mesasList.add(new Mesas(jsonObject.getString("num_mesa"), jsonObject.getString("mesero")));

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR DE CONEXION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }

              //Asociacion de el adaptador a el RecyclerView
              adapterMesas = new MyMesasRecyclerViewAdapter(mesasList, mListener);
              recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterMesas);


           }
```

Comment: yo llamo al listado desde el evento onCreateView ese es el error? en donde deberia llamarlo